# Display field in views-view-field--field_title.html.twig

Tags: views, theming, entities, 8

If I have view with fields:

```
field title [hidden]
field text [hidden]
field image [hidden]
field display
```

and I make rewrite in "display" field with "title" and "text" field added, how can I print content of field "image" (url of this image) with views-view-field--field_display.html.twig? I need wrapper with image url from this field. I see all available variables (view, field, row, output) in template and suggestion to fetch output with construct:

```
data = row[field.field_alias]
```

but when I try to write twig code with my field_image alias it's not showing me anything. Field with image is set up to display just url to image. I translated few code lines from drupal 7 to twig, but I am unable to see anything in kint, just dump show me some key strings. Views create block and I am placing this block on my page.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: you want to print the image url? is that your question?

Comment: Yes. It will be for field wrapper. Field are set up to display with HTML list, each field in list is <li class="slide"> content with title and text</li> and I want to wrapp each slide with image <div style="background-image: url( {{ field_with_image_url }} ) > {{ output -}} <div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [URL FORMATTER](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_url_formatter) module

> This module add a url formatter for image field. Then you can output image url directly.

Enable the module, then in views, click on your image field, and change the Formatter to Image url.

```
{{ fields.field_image.content }}  // will display url instead of picture
```

Comment: @Jack how did it go?

Comment: I've figured out that I have already installed that module, turned on and this field is set up to display url. I think I put wrong twig to print that field. What I am doing now is trying to display my field in 
views-view-fields--myview.html.twig 
not in 
views-view-field--myfield.html.twig

but not success yet.

Comment: `I want to wrapp each slide` is each slide is a row? and what is `{{ output }}` ?

Comment: NOW IT WORKS!  I tried to overwrite a wrong template file, in the template for all rows for fields it working just perfect! Now it's time to twig it  in my complicated way! Thank you again for support!